# Error : Invalid Tuple Value with POST or GET using Web3 js

Tags: node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js, quorum

I have created a quorum network composed of 3 nodes with raft based on this tutorial [here](https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/)

Able to deploy smart contract and execute functions with truffle console

But I am unable to POST or GET  using web3 js from the node?

Here is shown as below.

[image]

Comment: please share your js code

Comment: thanks but i found the solution the abi was wrong